# How to use the parameter "annot_kws" of the function "sns.heatmap" to revise the annotaion text?

Tags: matplotlib, annotations, seaborn, heatmap

How can I draw such a heatmap using the "seaborn.heatmap" function?
The color shades are determined by matrix A and the annotation of each grid is determined by matrix B.
For example, if I get a matrix, I want its color to be displayed according to the z-score of this matrix, but the annotation remains the matrix itself.
I know I should resort to the parameter 'annot_kws', but how exactly should I write the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of simply setting `annot=True`, [`annot=`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) can be set to a dataframe (or 2D numpy array, or a list of lists) with the same number of rows and columns as the data.  That way, the coloring will be applied using the `data`, and the annotation will come from `annot`. Seaborn will still take care to use white text for the dark cells and black text for the light ones.

`annot_kws=` is used to change the [text properties](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.text), typically the fontsize. But you also could change the font itself, or the alignment if you'd used multiline text.

Here is an example using numbers 1 to 36 as annotation, but the numbers modulo 10 for the coloring. The `annot_kws` are used to enlarge and rotate the text. (Note that when the annotation are strings, you also need to set the format, e.g. `fmt=''`).

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

a = pd.DataFrame({'count': [1, 2, 3]})

matrix_B = np.arange(1, 37).reshape(6, 6)  # used for annotations
matrix_A = (matrix_B % 10)  # used for coloring
sns.heatmap(data=matrix_A, annot=matrix_B,
            annot_kws={'size': 20, 'rotation': 45},
            square=True, cbar_kws={'label': 'last digit'})
```

[image: sns.heatmap with coloring different from labels]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !!! (*￣︶￣)